# MySQL Import into Innodb table severely spikes at a certain point

Tags: database, innodb, mysql, server

I'm trying to migrate a 30GB database from one server to another.

The short story is that at a certain point through the process, the amount of time it takes to import records severely increases as a spike. The following is from using the SOURCE command to import a chunk of 500k records (out of about ~25-30 million throughout the database) that was exported as an sql file that was ssh tunnelled over to the new server:

```
...

Query OK, 2871 rows affected (0.73 sec)
Records: 2871  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 2870 rows affected (0.98 sec)
Records: 2870  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 2865 rows affected (0.80 sec)
Records: 2865  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 2871 rows affected (0.87 sec)
Records: 2871  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 2864 rows affected (2.60 sec)
Records: 2864  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 2866 rows affected (7.53 sec)
Records: 2866  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 2879 rows affected (8.70 sec)
Records: 2879  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 2864 rows affected (7.53 sec)
Records: 2864  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 2873 rows affected (10.06 sec)
Records: 2873  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

...
```

The spikes eventually average to 16-18 seconds per ~2800 rows affected. Granted I don't usually use Source for a large import, but for the sakes of showing legitimate output, I used it to understand when the spikes happen. Using mysql command or mysqlimport yields the same results. Even piping the results directly into the new database instead of through an sql file has these spikes.

As far as I can tell, this happens after a certain amount of records are inserted into a table. The first time I boot up a server and import a chunk that size, it goes through just fine. Give or take the estimated amount it handles until these spikes occur. I can't correlate that because I haven't consistently replicated the issue to evidently conclude that. There are ~20 tables that have sub 500,000 records that all imported just fine when those 20 tables were imported through a single command. This seems to only happen to tables that have an excessive amount of data. Granted, the solutions I've come cross so far seem to only address the natural DR that occurs when you import over time (The expected output in my case was that eventually at the end of importing 500k records, it would take 2-3 seconds per ~2800, whereas it seems the questions were addressing that at the end it shouldn't take that long). This comes from a single sugarCRM table called 'campaign_log', which has ~9 million records. I was able to import in chunks of 500k back onto the old server i'm migrating off of without these spikes occuring, so I assume this has to do with my new server configuration. Another thing is that whenever these spikes occur, the table that it is being imported into seems to have an awkward way of displaying the # of records via count. I know InnoDB gives count estimates, but the number doesn't succeed the ~, indicating the estimate. It usually is accurate and that each time you refresh the table, it doesn't change the amount it displays (This is based on what it reports through PHPMyAdmin)

Here's the following commands/InnoDB system variables I have on the new server:

INNODB System Vars:

```
+---------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                  |
+---------------------------------+------------------------+
| have_innodb                     | YES                    |
| ignore_builtin_innodb           | OFF                    |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing        | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index      | ON                     |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size | 8388608                |
| innodb_autoextend_increment     | 8                      |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances    | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size         | 8589934592             |
| innodb_change_buffering         | all                    |
| innodb_checksums                | ON                     |
| innodb_commit_concurrency       | 0                      |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets      | 500                    |
| innodb_data_file_path           | ibdata1:10M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir            |                        |
| innodb_doublewrite              | ON                     |
| innodb_fast_shutdown            | 1                      |
| innodb_file_format              | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_format_check        | ON                     |
| innodb_file_format_max          | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_per_table           | OFF                    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method             | fsync                  |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted     | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery           | 0                      |
| innodb_io_capacity              | 200                    |
| innodb_large_prefix             | OFF                    |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout        | 50                     |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size          | 8388608                |
| innodb_log_file_size            | 5242880                |
| innodb_log_files_in_group       | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir       | ./                     |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      | 75                     |
| innodb_max_purge_lag            | 0                      |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups      | 1                      |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct           | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time          | 0                      |
| innodb_open_files               | 300                    |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks      | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size         | 20                     |
| innodb_purge_threads            | 1                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead        | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold     | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads          | 8                      |
| innodb_replication_delay        | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout      | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments        | 128                    |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay          | 6                      |
| innodb_stats_method             | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata        | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages       | 8                      |
| innodb_strict_mode              | OFF                    |
| innodb_support_xa               | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops          | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks              | ON                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency       | 0                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay       | 10000                  |
| innodb_use_native_aio           | ON                     |
| innodb_use_sys_malloc           | ON                     |
| innodb_version                  | 5.5.39                 |
| innodb_write_io_threads         | 8                      |
+---------------------------------+------------------------+
```

System Specs:

```
Intel Xeon E5-2680 v2 (Ivy Bridge) 8 Processors
15GB Ram
2x80 SSDs
```

CMD to Export:

```
mysqldump -u <olduser> <oldpw>, <olddb> <table> --verbose --disable-keys --opt | ssh -i <privatekey> <newserver> "cat > <nameoffile>"
```

Thank you for any assistance. Let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I increased the innodb_log_file_size from 5MB to 1024MB. While it did significantly increase the amount of records I imported (Never went above 1 second per 3000 rows), it also fixed the spikes. There were only 2 in all the records I imported, but after they happened, they immediately went back to taking sub 1 second.